# Infinite List in Flutter Application

Tags: list, flutter, flutter-layout, infinite-scroll, infinite

I am migrating my application from android to flutter and till now I have used **ListView** in a flutter. my question is, is there any specialized technique to handle a large amount of data in the flutter? for reference, you can look at android **RecyclerView**. it handles in-memory views and recycles its runtime. so how to achieve functionality like RecyclerView in Flutter? or it's not necessary for the flutter?

Comment: use `ListView.builder`

Comment: Flutter `ListView` is analog of ListView in android. `ListView.builder` is analog of RecyclerView.

Comment: The [Write Your First Flutter App](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) uses the `ListView.builder` as an example but you can get more information on [Working with long lists here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/lists/long-lists/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `ListView.builder` without specifying the `itemCount` parameter.

Here is the simplest example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Infinite List"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("$index");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Later, you can enhance this by fetching real data. You could show a 'CircularProgressIndicator' in the last item of the list while waiting for the new data.

```
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < data.length) {
        // Show your info
        return Text("$index");
      } else {
        getMoreData();
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
    itemCount: data.length + 1,
  ),
```

You can see that we trick the list by adding an index, and calling for more data when displaying that final index.

`getMoreData()` would include a call to `setState()` to force a rebuild and to take into account the new data.

Comment: I have added some explanation for an infinite list with real data.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a simple infinite list widget based on [chemamolins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116511/9449426)'s answer. It accepts an `itemBuilder` to build the current item and `onRequest` callback to request more data when the user scrolls to the bottom.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef Future<List<T>> RequestFn<T>(int nextIndex);
typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, T item, int index);

class InifiniteList<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final RequestFn<T> onRequest;
  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;

  const InifiniteList(
      {Key? key, required this.onRequest, required this.itemBuilder})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InifiniteListState<T> createState() => _InifiniteListState<T>();
}

class _InifiniteListState<T> extends State<InifiniteList<T>> {
  List<T> items = [];
  bool end = false;

  _getMoreItems() async {
    final moreItems = await widget.onRequest(items.length);
    if (!mounted) return;

    if (moreItems.isEmpty) {
      setState(() => end = true);
      return;
    }
    setState(() => items = [...items, ...moreItems]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index < items.length) {
          return widget.itemBuilder(context, items[index], index);
        } else if (index == items.length && end) {
          return const Center(child: Text('End of list'));
        } else {
          _getMoreItems();
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 80,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
      itemCount: items.length + 1,
    );
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
child: InifiniteList<String>(
  onRequest: requestItems,
  itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
    color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.purple.shade100 : Colors.lime.shade100,
    child: Text(item, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
  ),
),
```

```
// normally this is the place where you request the next batch of items
// on the network.
Future<List<String>> requestItems(int nextIndex) {
  const pageSize = 15;
  var result = List<String>.generate(pageSize, (i) => "Item: ${nextIndex + i + 1}");
  return Future<List<String>>.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    () => result,
  );
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=6ae326a7422736d6011ee1006819b123&null_safety=true)